# Can I create a model for the predictors using the response and outcomes?

Tags: r, regression, linear

I have a data set where the probability for player 1 win is given, and also 4 different outcomes which are possible (2:0, 2:1, 1:2, 0:2) Where the first 2 is Player 1 won, and the other 2 is player 2 won.

I have calculated the proportion of the different outcomes for different probabilities for different values of Player 1 probability. I would like to have probabilities for the different outcomes. I still need everything to sum up to.

For R users, this is what I have done:

Data file: http://www.megafileupload.com/sVoM/data.Rdata?download_token=75ea727b694bda64eb978c096709a6b3e6b7f2bb3ff8a18fa03099b828b97794

```
library(dplyr) ; library(plyr)

data <- read.table(file.choose())
cut <- c(seq(0.5,1,0.05))
data$cut<- cut(data$prob, cut)


tab <- ddply(data, c("cut"), summarise,
    "2:0"    = sum(outcome == "2:0")/length(cut),
    "2:1" = sum(outcome == "2:1")/length(cut),
    "1:2" = sum(outcome == "1:2")/length(cut),
    "0:2" = sum(outcome == "0:2")/length(cut))
```

Looking at the plots there is some interaction.

```
plot(tab[,2], main = "2:0")
plot(tab[,3], main = "2:1")
plot(tab[,4], main = "1:2")
plot(tab[,5], main = "0:2")
```

Now I need to create one model or extract some kind of regression linear/maybe some polynomial from the plots.